# Racket: Macros generated by macros defined as macroname.0

Tags: macros, racket

I'm trying to learn a bit about Racket and its macro system. My introduction has been writing a thin wrapper around the [IEX stock API](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/). My prep reading included Greg Hendershott's [Fear of Macros](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/all.html), the [Racket Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html#(part._.Macro-.Generating_.Macros)) (in particular, the section on macro-generating macros and surrounding documentation), and other online resources.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
(iex-op* chart dividends quote)
```

to generate the functions `iex-chart`, `iex-dividends`, et c. The use of a syntax transformer seemed like a natural fit to me since I don't think I could easily write a function-generating function with a clean syntax and multiple arguments.

So:

```
(define-syntax-rule (iex-op* op0 ...)
  (begin
    (iex-op op0) ...))
```

This assumes a working `iex-op` syntax transformer:

```
(define iex-base-url (string->url "https://api.iextrading.com"))
(define iex-ver "1.0")

(define-syntax (iex-op stx)
  (syntax-case stx (quote) ; quote is one of the operations
    [(_ oper)
     (with-syntax ([op-name (format-id stx "iex-~a" #'oper)])
         #'(define (op-name ticker . args)
             (let ([op-url
                    (combine-url/relative
                        iex-base-url
                        (string-join
                          `(,iex-ver
                            "stock"
                            ,(symbol->string ticker)
                            ,(symbol->string (syntax-e #'oper))
                            ,(string-join args "/")) "/"))])
              (string->jsexpr (http-response-body (get http-requester op-url))))))]))
```

My problem arises not with the `iex-op` macro, which appears to do the Right Thing, but with the use of `iex-op*`, which does not:

```
Welcome to Racket 6.3
> (enter! "iex.rkt")
> (iex-op quote)
> iex-<TAB><TAB>
iex-base-url iex-op       iex-op*      iex-quote    iex-ver
> (iex-op* chart dividends)
> iex-<TAB><TAB>
iex-base-url    iex-dividends.0 iex-op*         iex-ver
iex-chart.0     iex-op          iex-quote
```

The `op*`-defined functions are suffixed with `.0`. I don't know why, and I can't find documentation about it conveniently despite some hours of searching.

When I run the macro expander in DrRacket, I find that `(iex-op* chart dividends)` actually does expand to

```
(begin (iex-op chart) (iex-op dividends))
```

as desired. What's worse, when I reproduce the results of the syntax transformation in the REPL, it works!

```
> (begin (iex-op chart) (iex-op dividends))
> iex-<TAB><TAB>
iex-base-url    iex-chart.0     iex-dividends.0 iex-op*         iex-ver
iex-chart       iex-dividends   iex-op          iex-quote
```

What am I missing?  I'll readily admit my code probably needs some substantial clean-up (I'm slowly bending my Python/C/etc. mind), but I'm rather less concerned about its aesthetic and more about what arcanum is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.0` suffix isn’t actually a suffix on the name of the generated binding—it indicates that the identifier was introduced by a macro and lives inside a macro scope. The root problem is your use of `format-id`.

Remember that Racket’s macro system is *hygienic*. This means that bindings introduced by macros can only be seen by macros. This makes autocomplete in the REPL a little more complicated, and I don’t think what the REPL does here is honestly a very helpful choice. That said, what you probably want to know is how to fix your code, not the intricacies of why the REPL shows macro-introduced bindings with a  `.0` suffix.

When you call `format-id`, the produced identifier will have the same lexical context as the first argument. You can think of this as essentially meaning that the produced identifier will live in the same lexical scope as that piece of syntax. In your case, you are providing `stx`, which represents the entire input form to the macro.

When you use `iex-op` directly, by writing `(iex-op quote)`, for example, then the `quote` identifier comes from the same lexical scope as the containing `(iex-op ....)` form. Therefore, when you call `format-id` and give it the `(iex-op ....)` form as the first argument, you still get an identifier that shares the same lexical scope as the `quote` identifier, and all is well.

**However**, when you use your `iex-op*` macro, it passes the `op0` syntax object through, but the surrounding `(iex-op ....)` form comes *from the `iex-op*` macro*. This means that `stx` now refers to the *scope of the inside of the `iex-op*` macro, **not** the scope of the `op0` identifier*. To fix this, change your call to `format-id` so that it creates an identifier with the same scope as the operation identifier rather than the surrounding syntax object:

```
(format-id #'oper "iex-~a" #'oper)
```

Now your macro will work as intended.

Before finishing up, ask yourself: what are some takeaways here? Here are a couple:

1. Breaking hygiene is subtle. When you decide to write an unhygienic macro (and `format-id` is unhygienic), think very hard about where you’re getting the lexical context from. Consider what will happen when users write macros over your macro.

   In this case, you’re lucky that you are the author of both `iex-op` and `iex-op*`, so you could fix `iex-op` after you ran into a problem with it. But if you were not the author of `iex-op`, only `iex-op*`, you would be in a much trickier situation. Think about these things whenever you write any unhygienic macro to avoid such problems down the line.
2. As a rule of thumb, when unhygienically forging a new identifier from another identifier, it’s best to use that other identifier as the source of the lexical context. That way, the lexical scope of the identifier the user provided will be preserved, which is what users expect.

Arguably, some of the examples in Fear of Macros that use `format-id` are sloppy in this respect. It might be worth trying to improve them to set a better example.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! As you guessed, the Fear of Macros really  told me how to format the identifier, but I didn't understand the scope. I had an intuition it was a scope problem, but I mistakenly suspected it would be an issue of the transformation phase. Thank you so much!

Comment: I hadn't updated FoM in some years. Today I worked through a backlog of fixes, including improving the examples/explanation of the `lctx` arg to `format-id` and `datum->syntax`. Live site is updated.